# Checkbox issue in custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I want to select all **CheckBox** from **Custom ListView** on single Button click .

But when I have more than 9 items in ListView I am getting NullPointerException in below second line of code.

```
View vi= diffeneceLv.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.conschkbx);
```

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? That should make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting it wrong, `ListView` re-uses your rows, which means number of created rows/layouts in memory are not equal to your items in array.

Typically `ListView` re-sets the new data to previous row upon scroll.

I would suggest you to study [this blog post](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/), here the author is maintaing the Checked state and then setting it accordingly in `getView()` of adapter.

The author have created an array of bolean like this:

```
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
```

and storing the state of check or uncheck, and later accessing it from `getView()`, what you will do is, you will store `true` for all index and refresh your adapter. It'll select all your rows.

Here is [another post](http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT hold references of individual views for this purpose, as they are recycled.

For your convenience, `ListView` holds a `BooleanSparseArray` to store what items are checked.  This array contains a map of item id (index/position of items in adapter) to a boolean value.

Since `ListView` does all that for you, its good to **avoid re-inventing the wheel** and use `ListView`'s capability to hold checked state of its items. All you have to do is to set a choice mode for `ListView`: [`setChoiceMode(int choiceMode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29)

- To get any item's state, call [`isItemChecked(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked%28int%29) on `ListView`. Useful, if you are overriding `getView()` of adapter.
- To get all what's checked, call [`getCheckedItemPositions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) on `ListView`.
- To set checked value, call [`setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) on `ListView`.

Comment: Actually i want to add SelectAll button in layout with custom list view. on click on SelectAll button all checkbox from listview will get checked. but if i have lesser than 9 rows in listview it works proper else gives null pointer exception for checkbox.