# ListView with single choice to show unique selection

Tags: android, listview

I want to have a listview with a single choice. I use a CheckedTextView and when the user clicks on one row, i update the CheckedTextView. If he clicks on another row, the old selection retrieve the "normal" UI and the new selection takes the new UI.

It works fine on nexus 7 (4.2.2) but on galaxy S II (4.0.4), i have a case where i have two rows selected and i must click twice to have the right behavior.

I precise, i have set this property :

```
setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ecab"
    android:id="@+id/option"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ban_vhcl_list_off"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/fake" />
```

Here is my adapter

```
private class OptionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnItemClickListener {
    private final List<String> options;
    public OptionsAdapter(List<String> pOptions) {
        super(VehiculeActivity.this, R.layout.vehicule_list_item);
        options = pOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return options.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return options.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(VehiculeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.vehicule_list_item, null);
        CheckedTextView option = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option);
        option.setText(options.get(position));
        if (!option.isChecked()) {
            Log.d(Constants.D_TAG, "is NOT checked");
            option.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            option.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ban_vhcl_list_off);
        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.D_TAG, "is checked");
            option.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.check_box, 0);
            option.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ban_vhcl_list_on);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        CheckedTextView option = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.option);
        option.setChecked(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use the default `ArrayAdapter` with `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`

Comment: I use the `listView.setChoice(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` but i don't understand why on nexus 7 i have the behavior expected whereas on SGS II, i have a problem. I use a custom Adapter because, the data can change. For the moment, i have only String but in the future i could have another data type.

Comment: you have to map the selected item. [Here is a post](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/) about "Multiple Selection" with custom adapter. you have to modify a little to make it single selection.

Comment: I will see but this problem remains a mystery for me.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14100302/593709) may solve your mystery.

Comment: Finally, I use a static variable to know what position is selected and in the `getView()` function I test my sattic position with the position from `getView()`.